# Extract 'x' and 'y' co-ordinates of centroid in matlab

Tags: matlab, save, extract, tracking, centroid

I am doing a project which requires to get the x,y co ordinates of a thresholded image through camera feed. After thresholding and background subtraction, i have managed to get the output as black and white with centroid and its coordinates shown. Now i need to extract and save these centroid 'x' and 'y' values sepearately for further operations that will be based upon these 'x' and 'y' co-ordinates values.
here is the code for centroid that i have incorporated

```
stats = regionprops(bw, 'BoundingBox', 'Centroid');

    hold on

    for object = 1:length(stats)
        bb = stats(object).BoundingBox;
        bc = stats(object).Centroid;
        rectangle('Position',bb,'EdgeColor','r','LineWidth',2)
        plot(bc(1),bc(2), '-m+')
        a=text(bc(1)+15,bc(2), strcat('X: ', num2str(round(bc(1))), '    Y: ',                              num2str(round(bc(2)))));
        set(a, 'FontName', 'Arial', 'FontWeight', 'bold', 'FontSize', 12, 'Color', 'red');

    end

    hold off
```

How do i extract the 'x' and 'y' centroid values to be worked upon later?
Thankyou.

Comment: There is no question in here, or at least I cant see it

Comment: i'm sorry....my Q is...HOW do i extract the 'x' and 'y' coordinates seperately to be worked upon later?

Comment: `bc(1)` is X and `bc(2)` is y in each iteration....

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement Ander's comment, the coordinates of the centroids are stored in the array `bc`, which you are using after calling `rectangle` to plot the said centroids. If you need to use them for later you can put them in a `N x 2` array, where `N` is actually `length(stats)`, before the loop.

Using [vertcat](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html) to pile up every x- and y-coordinate, that would look like this:

```
stats = regionprops(bw, 'BoundingBox', 'Centroid');

AllCentroids = vertcat(stats.Centroid);
```

Which is like `bc` but contains all centroid coordinates. You could do the same with the coordinates of the Bounding boxes. Here your array would be `N x 4`:

```
AllBB = vertcat(stats.BoundingBox);
```

You could also get rid of a few lines in the loop and put them outside. For instance:

```
a=text(AllCentroids(:,1)+15,AllCentroids(:,2), strcat('X: ', num2str(round(AllCentroids(:,1))), '    Y: ',                              num2str(round(AllCentroids(:,2)))));
set(a, 'FontName', 'Arial', 'FontWeight', 'bold', 'FontSize', 12, 'Color', 'red');

   for object = 1:length(stats)

        rectangle('Position',AllBB(k,:),'EdgeColor','r','LineWidth',2)
        plot(AllCentroids(object,1),AllCentroids(object,2), '-m+')

    end
```

Hope that makes things clearer!